# best way to run different commands depending on OS in bash

Tags: windows, macos, bash, scripting

In a bash script is there an "official" way to run different commands based on, for example, OS version. I mean in a way that you can basically set it once at the top and then call it the same way everywhere else.
I've tried to use aliases but that seems to be a crapshoot and doesn't really work on some systems (one is Windows 7 using win-bash).

For example, this is what I tried:

```
if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then
    alias p4cli=./bin/p4
else
    alias p4cli=C:\bin\p4.exe
fi

p4cli login
```

It works on Mac if I use `shopt -s expand_aliases` but win-bash doesn't have shopt.
I'm assuming there's a better way than aliases to do this?

Comment: For this particular example, it will suffice to set the `PATH` correctly before running the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine underlying OS in bash it is better to depend on env variable `OSTYPE`. The bash manpage says that the variable OSTYPE stores the name of the operation system:

> OSTYPE Automatically set to a string that describes the operating
>   system on which bash is executing. The default is system- dependent.

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
   p4cli="./bin/p4"
else
   p4cli="C:\bin\p4.exe"
fi

"$p4cli" login
```

Answer (score 2):

Use variables, not aliases.

```
if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then
    p4cli=(./bin/p4)
else
    p4cli=('C:\bin\p4.exe')
fi

"${p4cli[@]}" login
```

We make the variables arrays so that arguments can be added to the commands later if required.

Answer (score 1):

Make the process that calls `p4cli` responsible for adding the correct directory to its `PATH` variable. Then you need only call `p4cli login` without worry about its exact location.

Presumably, you would do this from a machine-specific (or at least OS-specific) `.bash_profile`, which can just hard-code the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the command in a variable?

```
if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then
    p4cli='./bin/p4'
else
    p4cli='C:\bin\p4.exe'
fi

$p4cli login
```